# How to use Time Profiler to check memory consumption?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, profiler

When trying to test my app I don't see any useful information about what causes memory consumption in my code.

I had choose as a target (upper left in the Time Profiler window) the physical iPhone device and my app.
I made a profiling build inside Xcode (`Product -> Build For -> Profiling`), but when I start record I can see only this:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Is there something else I should do ?
I am using Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inspect memory usage you can use XCode built in memory tool (the 6th icon in XCode Navigator), or use **Allocations** instrument for more detailed report. Info about Allocations is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html).
With Time Profiler you can measure usage CPU time, not memory consumption.